# JSF AJAX URL Param update

Tags: java, ajax, url, jsf, param

I have a scenario where I have a page that has the ability to display a datatable. The datatable data is selected by the user BUT it must be possible to provide a direct URL to load the specific data into the table. To achieve this I am using params in the URI to determine the service that should be loaded (www.example.com?service=1).

User clicks one service and the URL changes to www.example.com?service=2 and data from that service is loaded via AJAX and shown on the page. No postback, only partial page refresh. I want to avoid complete page reloads as only the datatable needs reloading.

1. How would I go about updating the the URL param from a backing bean (ie. from www.example.com?service=1 to www.example.com?service=2) without reloading the page?
2. How would I go about reading the new URL param without resubmitting the page?

UPDATE

At the moment I am redirecting the whole page with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

and trying to read in the param using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().‌​get("service");
```

However that really isn't what I want to achieve at it is reloading a lot of unnecessary data and it makes managing other properties on the page more complex! I want to update the params and read them but ONLY reload the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to JSf but I think this will help, it is a simple example:

Let's suppose you have a `<h:inputText>` with a object property as value, like:

```
<h:form id="formUser">
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}" id="userName" />
</h:form>
```

If you need to update the name property with a ajax call:

```
<h:commandButton value="Update user" action="#{userBean.updateUserName}">
    <f:ajax render="formUser:userName" execute="formUser:userName" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The render attribute will make the element reload on the page. The execute will make the element set the value, in this case, to the `name` property of `UserBean`

This way, when you type a name on that `inputText` and click the `commandButton`, it will execute the set method for name and re-render the input on the view so the new value will appear.

But if you need a `link` here is a example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/):

```
<h:link value="Login page + Param " outcome="login" >
    <f:param name="username" value="mkyong" />
</h:link>
```

Is that what you really want?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, thats not quite what I was looking for. I have no problems performing partial reloads of the page using ajax in general. My problem is performing an AJAX URL param update and then an AJAX URL param read. So I want to change the URL from www.example.com?service=1 to www.example.com?service=2 via ajax without reloading the page.